# Presto - Oracle and Mongodb join query

Tags: mongodb, presto

I am doing some POC to join Oracle and MongoDB data using presto join.

Just followed the following document for install and running.

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html

Is it the latest version? I see some other version on some forums.

For example, seeing a different version in,

http://future-arena.blogspot.com/2013/11/presto-single-node-installation.html

Not sure which is the correct one.

For oracle connector, followed the following link.

https://github.com/marcelopaesrech/presto-oracle

Looks like it has some issues. issues.

When I run a query it hangs at the following line as getSchemas() return 150k records.

```
try (Connection connection = driver.connect(connectionUrl,
                connectionProperties);
                ResultSet resultSet = connection.getMetaData().getSchemas()) {
            ImmutableSet.Builder<String> schemaNames = ImmutableSet.builder();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String schemaName = resultSet.getString(1).toLowerCase();
                log.info("Listing schemas: " + schemaName);
                schemaNames.add(schemaName);
            }
            return schemaNames.build();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

Not sure, If i am doing anything wrong.

Even, hardcoding to one schema is causing some other error like, duplicate columns ..

Is this the right presto oracle driver.

Also, tried getting presto mongo driver from the following link and build is failing.

https://github.com/miniway/presto/tree/mongodb

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That presto-oracle plugin is the right one.  I have been using it for a week now.

Unfortunately, to get the mongodb connector, you would have to git clone this branch of PrestoDB:
https://github.com/miniway/presto

```
git clone https://github.com/miniway/presto.git
git fetch origin
git checkout mongodb
mvn clean install -Dskip-tests
```

then copy presto-mongodb-0.136-SNAPSHOT folder in target to your plugins folder in presto.  (I also renamed it to just 'mongodb' but not sure if that necessary)

The good news is there is a PR for the branch above, so it should be merged in the future.

Comment: The MongoDB connector is part of Presto, so this workaround is no longer necessary.